# Configure Wordpress to connect to Mysql DB using SSH tunneling

Tags: mysql, ssh

Problem: Configure wordpress to use a remote mysql database only available using and SSH tunneling.

Stage:
I have a wordpress instance over an apache server on machine (called WP_server). WP_server, does not have Mysql server and has blocked port except 80 (http) and 22 (ssh).

In other place is another machine (Mysql_server) which has a MySQL instance. This server can provide a database to WP_server.

These two server have ssh access.

How should I configure wordpress to use ssh tunneling?

Comment: First of all this is not a programming question. However, your question is a bit incomplete, too. If you have a tunnel established and running, what does WordPress (or any other application for that matter) have to care about?

Answer (score 4):

You should create a [ssh tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) between the 2 serves. Then you can connect from the WP with only the mysql server ip.

```
ssh -f user@personal-server.com -L 2000:personal-server.com:25 -N
```

The `-f` tells ssh to go into the background just before it executes the command.

This is followed by the username and server you are logging into.

The `-L 2000:personal-server.com:25` is in the form of `-L local-port:host:remote-port`.

Finally the `-N` instructs OpenSSH to not execute a command on the remote system.

via [Revsys](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom DB handler in wordpress. Extend the wpdb class located in `wp-includes/wpdb.php` file, and modify things to fit your needs. Be sure to create an instance called `$wpdb` at the very end of it.

Then, drop the file in `wp-content/db.php`. It will be used in place of the wpdb class.